# MySQL - SELECT with LEFT JOIN optimization

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 3 tables to select from.  2 of them are always necessary (`tbl_notes`, `tbl_clients`) while the 3rd is optional (`tbl_notes_categories`).

I've always used a `LEFT JOIN` in my queries with questionable correlating records to the primary table.

But I'm not getting any results with the query below.

Would someone point out how I'm using the LEFT JOIN incorrectly?

```
SELECT n.*, c.clientname, nc.notecategoryname 
FROM tbl_notes n, tbl_clients c 
LEFT JOIN tbl_notes_categories nc ON n.categoryid = nc.categoryid 
WHERE n.clientid = c.clientid 
AND c.clientid = 12345 
ORDER BY n.dateinserted DESC
```

In fact, I'm getting a sql error.
**#1054 - Unknown column 'n.categoryid' in 'on clause'**

`categoryid` certainly does exist in `tbl_notes`

I probably need to brush up on how JOINS really work.  I'm guessing I cannot have a LEFT JOIN with 2 database tables before it?

On a side note, I can foresee times when there will be multiple required tables, with several optional tables.  (in this case `tbl_notes_categories` is optional)

Comment: Try converting the implicit join between `tbl_notes` and `tbl_clients` into an explicit `INNER JOIN`.  That's what's going on behind the scenes anyway.  (Assuming that it is an inner join, and not a cross join, as @LifeInTheGrey suggests.)

Comment: have you tried making the cross join explicit?

Comment: To avoid error swap tables in FROM clause: `FROM  tbl_clients c, tbl_notes n ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the column `categoryid` exists in the `tbl_notes` table...

Try rewriting the query to use the `JOIN` syntax, rather than using the old-school comma as the join operator.  (If the problem isn't a misnamed column, I suspect the problem is in mixing the two types of syntax... but this is just a suspicion, I have no reason to test mixing old-style comma joins with `JOIN` keywords.)

I'd write the statement like this:

```
SELECT n.*, c.clientname, nc.notecategoryname 
  FROM tbl_notes n
  JOIN tbl_clients c 
    ON n.clientid = c.clientid 
  LEFT
  JOIN tbl_notes_categories nc 
    ON nc.categoryid = n.categoryid
 WHERE c.clientid = 12345
 ORDER BY n.dateinserted DESC
```

(Actually, I would specify the individual columns to return from `n`, rather than using `n.*`, but that's just a style preference, not a SQL syntax requirement.)

Comment: So, I keep the `LEFT JOIN` on optionally used tables, while my required tables will use the `JOIN`?  Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @coffeemonitor: yes, the comma join operator works like the `JOIN` keyword, except that the `JOIN` syntax allows for predicates to be specified in an `ON` clause, and allows for outer joins.

Comment: got it.  I didn't know the comma was considered old-style.  I think I can see why. Your solution worked. Thank you